# Why lightning-helptext is giving an arror

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm using the lightning-helptext in my aura component and when I upload the code to my sandbox I have the error:

```
Invalid Descriptor Format: lightning-helptext[COMPONENT]
```

I copy and past the snipped code from the documentation:

```
<lightning-helptext content="The tooltip displays on the lower left of the icon or above the icon if space is available. It automatically adjusts its position according to the viewport."></lightning-helptext>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using aura components, this is the syntax:

```
<lightning:helptext content="The tooltip displays on the lower left of the icon or above the icon if space is available. It automatically adjusts its position according to the viewport."/>
```

It's explained in [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext/example)